# How do I remove the boulders on my farm?

Tags: harvest-moon-3d-a-new-beginning

On my farm, there are these two big boulders; I haven't gotten the ultimate hammer yet, however in my experience of Harvest Moon, rocks and boulder get sequentially bigger for each level of hammer required to break them, and these look too big for the ultimate hammer, considering what the Iron Hammer breaks. Also, in Harvest Moon DS, to break the biggest boulders by the waterfall I needed the Sword, not the hammer.

So I am wondering what I need to do to break these.

Comment: Are you talking about the giant boulders on the east and west sides of your farm?

Comment: @fbueckert yes, the ones that seem to block 2 exits on either side

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The boulders on the sides of your farm are completely indestructible; not even the Ultimate Hammer can break them.

The only way to get rid of them is to continue the Town Restoration, and keep adding new buildings to the town.  As you do so, the Harvest Sprites will hide music in them.  Finding the music, and playing it successfully will trigger different things, based on which song you're playing, one of which will remove a boulder somewhere.  The first (and only) one I've managed to remove has given more space for the town, not the farm.  To give you an idea when that will happen, I'm at the end of Town Restoration #3 (only have one left), and I haven't managed to expand my farm yet.  And I do have the Ultimate Hammer, and the other fully upgraded tools, and I'm in Year 2, Summer.

As it is, even with the Ultimate Watering Can, I don't have enough energy to water more than a dozen fields or so.  Currently, expanding the farm would be counter productive, as I barely have enough energy to get everything done as is.

Comment: i don't really care about expanding my farm out more it's just that the rock on the left side is taking up space for me to set down another field, since it's apparent that it may take me quite some time before they are removed i guess i'll have to rethink where my main crop is located so to avoid

Answer (score 0):

Do the music sheets as they come, at the end of restoration plan 3, the right side of your farm unlocks and there is a water spout thing on a terraced thing. I do not know how to describe it, but I have like 10 plots of land on that just for crops, there is also a huge space for you to put another barn/farm area down. I use it as a tree space, as there are 10 different trees. The only way to get the items or areas that you need for your farm to become amazeballs is to do ALL the music sheets you can get your hands on, and fast.

Nearly done with restoration plan 4 myself, and I just hit year 2 it is like spring 2 or something.

Also, here's an AWESOME website that has ALL the info you need about anything, still reading new stuff on it! 
http://fogu.com/hm11/

GOOD LUCK